# How to retrieve data from collection using find() method in custom date format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

my Schema

Customers.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Customers = mongoose.Schema({
    CustomerID: { type: String, default: "" },
    Name: { type: String, default: "" },
    Email: { type: String, default: "" },
    PhoneNumber: { type: String, default: "" },
    Join_Date: { type: Date, default: null }
}, { collection: 'Customers' });
export default mongoose.model('Customers', Customers);
```

my router controller

```
import Customers from "./Customers";
router.post('/List_All_Customers', (req, res) => {
    Customers.find().lean().exec().then((Data) => {
        res.json({Data: Data});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

My Current Result

```
{
    Data: [
        {
            CustomerID: "6ad050d4-04ac-41f2-8c93-49f68f106889",
            Name: "Uday Kumar",
            Email: "uday@blaabla.com",
            PhoneNumber: "+91-991010191",
            Join_Date: "2018-04-24T12:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            CustomerID: "792b67f9-9026-43bc-9017-46cd2568b4e9",
            Name: "Prem Kumar",
            Email: "prem@blaabla.com",
            PhoneNumber: "+91-881010091",
            Join_Date: "2018-04-24T15:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Expecting Result

```
{
    Data: [
        {
            CustomerID: "6ad050d4-04ac-41f2-8c93-49f68f106889",
            Name: "Uday Kumar",
            Email: "uday@blaabla.com",
            PhoneNumber: "+91-991010191",
            Join_Date: "Apr-24 2018, 12:00:00"
        },
        {
            CustomerID: "792b67f9-9026-43bc-9017-46cd2568b4e9",
            Name: "Prem Kumar",
            Email: "prem@blaabla.com",
            PhoneNumber: "+91-881010091",
            Join_Date: "Apr-24 2018, 15:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anyway in mongodb for result in custom dates. I am using mongoose mongodb connection in my project.

I can manipulate data using for loop with momentjs but it is taking time.

So i need one solution for my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comments are appreciated.

Comment: *"I can manipulate data using for loop with momentjs but it is taking time."* in reality that is your best option "if you actually change things" that is. Modern MongoDB releases have a `$dateToString`, but the output formats are limited. You really *"should not"* change this output though. This is data being sent to a client, and the ISO format is what that client really should be receiving. If the "client" wants to display in a different format, then it should do that itself, where it can specifically format for it's "locale". Dates are not the same in every country.

Comment: so there is no possible solution from mongodb other than limited $dateToString

Comment: mapReduce can do JavaScript manipulation on the server, but the response is a **single** BSON document and typically not practical. My main point is "do not do this". The output of dates is exactly as it is meant to be. Process different formats in the client instead is the better approach. Otherwise simply stick with altering the returned documents before moving them on.

Comment: thanks @NeilLunn for your anticipation and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You Can use javascript **map** function 
***like***

```
import Customers from "./Customers";
router.post('/List_All_Customers', (req, res) => {
    Customers.find().lean().exec().then((Data) => {
      Promise.resolve(arr.map(item=>{
       item.Join_Date = fnToConvertDateToYourFormate(item.Join_Date);
       return item;
      })).then(Data=>{
        res.json({Data: Data});
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

***OR***
You Can Use Mongoose MapReduce
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mapreduce_mapReduce

```
var o = {};
o.map = function () { 
this.Join_Date = fnToConvertDateToYourFormate(this.Join_Date);
emit(this.CustomerId,this)
}
o.reduce = function (k, vals) {  }
mongoose.model('Customers').mapReduce(o, function (err, results) {
  console.log(results)
});
```

Comment: i know how to do manipulation of json array using map , async and forEach , etc.

Comment: i just want to know is there any solution from mongodb

Comment: Okay .. so use mongoose mapReduce http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mapreduce_mapReduce

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregate query. An example for this query is given below:-

```
 db.customers.aggregate([      
     {$project: 
         {yearMonthDayUTC: 
             {$dateToString: 
               {format: "%Y-%m-%d", 
                date: "$date" 
               } 
             },
         }
      }
    ])
```

For this query, the date should be in ISO. So, while inserting element into the db, you can use `new Date()` as this returns the current date as a Date object. The mongo shell wraps the Date object with the ISODate helper.

An example for inserting data in db is given below:-

```
 db.sales.insert({  "_id" : 4,   "item" : "mansi",   "price" : 10,   "quantity" : 2,   "date" : new Date(Date.now())  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try mongoDB `$dateToString` aggregation.

```
Customers.aggregate([
  {
   $project: {
       "other_field": 1, // and so on as many fields you need
       Join_Date: {
         { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$Join_Date" } }
       }
    }
  }
]).then((Data) => {
        res.json({Data: Data});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

> Read more about it at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/

Comment: format is limited and i need in find method and i have to independently work on other fields

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar yeah format is little bit limited and yes you need defined other fields. Another approach is using mongoose middlewares but again it involves looping over.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to use $dateToString and $month together in aggregate to produce the required format.